# jQuery Reload Multiple Datatables With 1 Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have 2 datatables on the same page. I am using reload to reload them both as such:

```
setInterval( function () {
    jQuery('#tablepress-1').DataTable().ajax.reload();
    jQuery('#tablepress-2').DataTable().ajax.reload();
}, 30000 );
```

but this causes 2 calls ajax calls to the server. Server is already returning data for both tables in both calls. How to combine multiple reloads so that only 1 call is made to update both?

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a JSON call
2. and send both the content in a single ajax call.
3. On success, get both of the data and initialise the data table.

Example:

```js
// Use the Fetch Api (no library)
fetch('/your/path').then(function(data) {
      $('.table1').html(data.table1);
      $('.table2').html(data.table2);
      //now initialise the tables
});

// Or use jQuery (better support)
$.ajax({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/your/path',
  data: {}
})
  .done(function( data ) {
    $('.table1').html(data.table1);
    $('.table2').html(data.table2);
  });
```

Comment: great answer! Could be improved with some example code :)

Comment: //some rough sketch

Comment: Fetch(yourpath).then(function(data){ $('.table1'). html (data.table1); $('table2').html(data.table2); //now initialise the tables });//rought sketch, send from mobile.